# Pyspark find friendship pairs from friendship lists

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have data describing single directional friendship such as below:
For the first line, it means 1 added 3, 4, 8 as friends but doesn't know their responses, and if 3 added 1 as friend as well, they become a pair.

```
ID friendsList  
1  [3, 4, 8]  
2  [8]  
3  [1]  
4  [1]  
5  [6]  
6  [7]  
7  [1]  
8  [1, 2, 4]
```

How can I use PySpark and PySpark SQL to generate friendship pair that both of them are bi-directional friends? Sample output(distinct or not doesn't matter):

```
(1, 4)  
(1, 8)  
(1, 3)  
(2, 8)  
(3, 1)  
(4, 1)  
(8, 1)  
(8, 2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by `explode` function and self join as shown below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df = spark.createDataFrame(((1,[3, 4, 8]),(2,[8]),(3,[1]),(4,[1]),(5,[6]),(6,[7]),(7,[1]),(8,[1, 2, 4])),["c1",'c2'])
df.withColumn('c2',explode(df['c2'])).createOrReplaceTempView('table1')
>>> spark.sql("SELECT t0.c1,t0.c2 FROM table1 t0 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t0.c1 = t1.c2 AND t0.c2 = t1.c1").show()
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  8|  1|
|  1|  4|
|  2|  8|
|  4|  1|
|  8|  2|
|  3|  1|
|  1|  8|
+---+---+
```

use below if Dataframe API is preferred over spark SQL.

```
df = df.withColumn('c2',explode(df['c2']))
df.alias('df1') \
  .join(df.alias('df2'),((col('df1.c1') == col('df2.c2')) & (col('df2.c1') == col('df1.c2')))) \
  .select(col('df1.c1'),col('df1.c2'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving a problem bothered me quite a while. That works perfectly!